# Make DOM element effectively read-only

Tags: .net, dom, mshtml

I'm writing a .NET forms control to edit HTML using MSHTML.  I am creating some custom elements and want to make them effectively read-only.  I thought I could go about this by focusing on the entire element any time focus entered anywhere in that element but the HtmlElement.Focus() doesn't select the entire element and I don't seem to be able to capture entry of the cursor.

Another option would be to raise an event whenever the text of the element is changed (on KeyDown I expect) but I can't get that event to fire, either.  Any ideas about why my expectations about event behavior is wrong or alternate suggestions for implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that setting the attribute:

```
contentEditable=false
```

Resulted in the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to apply readonly behavior to an User Input control, you can try using @readonly attribute of that control. Otherwise you could also add event listeners for appropriate UI events (keydown, mousedown) and prevent their default behavior (return false, or event.returnValue = false). As for custom events dispatch, you can indeed do that. Use event name that is known to IE. And another hint could be: register an onchange event handler and revert value of control to the value of defaultValue (property of any input controls).

Hope some of ideas will help.